# Where to save file on web service temporarily

Tags: c#, web-services

I am uploading a file to azure web service, then DO SOMETHING with that file, then erase it.

The service successfully receives the data I am sending I just can't seem to write to any location to save the file in the service.

Any ideas on where I can store temporarily?
(it works locally)

This is what I have tried

```
string temp2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(".");
string temp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");
FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(temp2 + "/tempLocation/streamtest.csv", FileMode.Create);
```

Comment: don't you have to specify a temp file path location when using the following `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".")` can you not create a folder on the server that you have rights to , to save the file ?

Comment: "." is the current directory, id expect that to work, but I would expect a web browser to be very limited where it can write files by default, temp is usually the place to go

Comment: where would the temp be located?  and what would be the best way to visually look at it?

Comment: @MethodMan I thought by putting the rest of that string in fileToupload I was specifying

Comment: I would have expected to see something like this for example @solarissf
`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/somepath/temp/")` and the temp would be the folder that your program would have full read/write permissions to on the server side

Comment: do I have to actually create "somepath" first?

Comment: you need to create a filepath on the server with the correct permissions same way you would if you wanted to save a file locally..

Comment: so I right clicked on my solution in visual studio.  created a folder called "tempLocation", but I do not see anywhere to grant permission to write.

Comment: You can't just work with the file in memory ?

Comment: @cosmo0 I would love to do that but couldn't figure out how to convert that stream I am receiving to a datatable, so I can then do a sqlbulkupload.

Comment: What's the content of what you are receiving ?

Comment: the original file is a csv file, but I have to manipulate some of the cells before I do an upload to sql.... the data is all different types, strings, floats, datetimes.

Comment: I think I got it... string temp4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/tempLocation");  I just right clicked in VS and created a folder, then hit publish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use [Path.GetTempPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h76cxdfc(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Another way - use [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)

Comment: okay, I tried GetTempPath, it did something....  Is there anywhere to go to see if I can physically go to look at it to see if it saved.  Like somewhere in visual studio?

Comment: @solarissf what for do you need to see it? If method Save did not throw excepion - file saved.

Comment: it was more for myself than anything else.  Thanks for the help